# qt : QSqlQuery returns vector of QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am querying a sqlite db using QSqlQuery class like this :

```
 QSqlQuery query("SELECT country FROM artist");
 while (query.next()) {
     QString country = query.value(0).toString();
     doSomething(country);
 }
```

Is there a way to get vector of QVariants directly from QSqlLite class? Something like this :

```
 QSqlQuery query("SELECT country FROM artist");
 while (query.next()) {
     std::vector< QVariant > allFields;
     allFields.push_back( query.value(0) );
     allFields.push_back( query.value(1) );
     allFields.push_back( query.value(2) );
     doSomething(allFields);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use boundValues:

```
QList<QVariant> allFields = query.boundValues().values();
```

P.S: I wouldn't use std-containers in Qt. Qt-containers have a major advantage - implicit sharing. I would suggest using QList instead of std::vector

Comment: Looks fine, but do I need to call bindValue() before calling boundValues? Is boundValues going to hold the current result of the query (after calling query.next()) ?